# creating new folder after taking a photo

Tags: java, android

I've visited many place for solution however I still couldn't figure out my error.

I've tried creating the folder manually, and the picture could be saved. If I delete the folder, I couldn't save the picture anymore. Could anyone kindly point out where is my mistake?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                        IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

                // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {                        
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                                + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                    }
                }

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                        +"tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));


                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else { //pick from file
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code.

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

if (!mediaStorageDir .exists()) {
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
}   

Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

You are using this below code

```
if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {                        
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                                + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                    }
                }
```

But in this you are not creating directory if it does not exist, you are just printing log that's why it is happening like this.

Comment: Hi there. Its the same. I couldn't press the "Tick" icon after taking a picture. However, if I already have the folder created, it works fine.

Comment: Because you are putting this code after calling `Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`  this line put it above the line and you are done.

Comment: Check for my updated answer, and still if you have any problem then do comment, will help you.

Comment: I've just tried. It doesn't work either.. I don't think it is because I put it in the onClick right? I've considered creating the directory before I even do the onClick, however, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

use Below code in onActivityResult

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
  }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

         }
```

Comment: Hi suresh, how would I be able to create another private void under onActivityResult. It will return me an error.

Comment: create separate method in your class. You have to call that method in OnActivityResult